# Sprites flicker in XNA

Tags: xna

I have player sprites and drawing them statically is no problem. But on updating and rendering them in the game loop they flicker for some reason. What could possibly cause this? They don't flicker all the time, but just now and then you see a sprite flicker.

Comment: How are you drawing your sprites?

Answer (score 1):

it's due to the use of float, do this before draw:

```
 Vector2 FixedPosition = new Vector2((int)SpritePosition.X, (int)SpritePosition.Y);

 SpriteBacth.Draw(Texture, FixedPosition,....);
```

Comment: This. And if you want to know why, read [Shawn Hargreaves' explanation](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/blogindex.html).  Search for Texture Filtering and read the article series.